# How to sort joomla VirtueMart component products by order?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I am using **joomla Version 1.5.23, VirtueMart version 2.0.6**

what I am trying is from the front end
**Joomla administrator area->Components->VirtueMart->Configuration->Configuration->Product Sort Order Settings->Default product sort order.**

and Use the **Default product sort order** drop-down menu to pick the preferred default sort order and i select **ordering** because **I want to sort products in ordering.**

**but nothing happens** so i want to know how can we do that from the **back end.**

any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually have that combination of Joomla and VM installed anywhere, but I'm 99% sure that it's just misleading labeling, in that "ordering" really should say "Select Ordering".  In other words, by clicking on that, you're not selecting any ordering, so VM isn't using an ORDER BY clause, thus leaving it to MySQL to return them in whatever order it happens to arrive at in your case.

If you have Firebug installed, you could inspect that element and see what the value of the option is (or just view the page source code), and I think you'll see that there is no value there.